# Unification and substitutions in first-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am currently learning about first-order logic and various resolution techniques.

When applying a substitution $\theta$ to two sentences $\alpha$ and $\beta$, for unification purposes, aside from 
SUBST($\theta$, $\alpha$) = SUBST($\theta$, $\beta$), does the resulting substitution have to be unique?

What I mean is, when unifying, when we check if SUBST($\theta$, $\alpha$) = SUBST($\theta$, $\beta$), is it OK if 
SUBST($\theta$, $\beta$) = $\beta$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify?  You asked, "when applying a substitution $\theta$ to two sentences … does the resulting substitution have to be unique?"  When you apply a substitution to an expression, you get another expression, not a substitution.  As to the very last bit of your questions, it's certainly possible for $\mathrm{SUBST}(\theta,\beta) = \beta$, e.g., when $\theta$ is the empty substitution.

Answer (score 1):

The *most general unifier* $\theta$ is unique in the sense that given any other unifier $\phi$, $\alpha \phi$ can be got from $\alpha \theta$ by a subtitution, and the same for $\beta$.